# std::istringstream from std::string without copying

Tags: c++, istringstream

I've been using this:

```
ifstream in("file.txt")
string line;    
getline(in,line);
istringstream iss(line);
...
```

for some simple parsing.
I would like to avoid unnecessary copying in order to improve performance so I tried:

```
ifstream in("huge_line.txt");
string line;
getline(in,line);
istringstream ss;
ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(const_cast<char*>(line.c_str()), line.size());
...
```

and it seems to do the job (significantly improve performance, that is). My question is, is this safe given the const_cast?
I mean, as long as I'm working with an istrinstream, the internal buffer should never get written to by the istringstream class, so the ss variable should remain in a valid state as long as the line variable is valid and unchanged, right?

Comment: `ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(&line.front(), line.size());` for short version, also avoids ugly cast

Comment: I wonder why `istringstream` doesn't have a constructor to move from a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `const_cast` is safe, because the underlying buffer of `std::string` is not `const`. And yes, as long as `line` does not expire while `ss` is being read from, your program should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

The effect of `ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf` is implementation-defined and hence doesn't necessarily do what you expect.

So, the effect of your altered code doesn't need to be equivalent to the initial one.